# Аппроксимация данных

Tags: python, numpy

У меня есть нулевой numpy массив с рефлексами (резкий скачок). Как аппроксимировать массив, чтобы рефлексы превратились в распределения, где значения вершин совпадают. Для понимания вопроса нарисовал картинку в paint, где 1й график - рефлексы, 2й - распределения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее всем спасибо. Всем PEACE

Comment: Добавьте попытки решения задачи.

Comment: @СергейКох сначала пробовал через numpy.ftt, однако рефлексы заполняют полностью весь график. Ряд Тейлора, Лагранджа, сплайны и полиномы Ньютона восстанавливают полностью все рефлексы, как они были изначально

Comment: Какой-нибудь ваш код "в студию!".)

Comment: @СергейКох начальный нулевой массив : `arr = np.zeros(180000)`

Comment: Судя по картинке его можно изрядно сократить.

Comment: У меня там четкая зависимость от угла. Если я буду сокращать массив, то будет появляться погрешность

Comment: Вот может поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209115/creating-gaussian-filter-of-required-length-in-python